# Disable email detection in SwiftUI's Text

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

The following code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Produces this
[image: Hello, World]

But the following code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello@gmail.com")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Produces this
[image: Email]

How can I make "hello@gmail.com" appear formatted like "Hello, World!" (no underline, no blue tint, remove link on click)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `verbatim:` form of `Text`, which will skip the parsing step:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: "hello@gmail.com")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @jnpdx!

Comment: One thing to remember is that `Text(verbatim:)` will use text as is - no translation

Comment: You can also use String("hello@gmail.com"), for example in a Label, where the verbatim version doesn't work.